# Quanteda tf-idf transform function in R

Tags: r, tf-idf, quanteda

I have used quanteda package and get two huge dfm **train** and **Valid**.

**train** and **valid** column are same.

I known use `dfm_tfidf` can get **tfidf** weight very fast on **tain**, 
but my problem is how to get **valid tfidf** on base on **tain idf**.

I try to use `pblapply` and for loop, but the run time really slow.

Here is my code, how to transform tfidf base on other idf in quanteda, or
any other way to speed up.

```
##
##
##  Idf
Idf <- function(x){
  n     <- nrow(x)
  check <- colSums(dfm_weight(x, "boolean"))
  sure  <- ifelse(check==0, n, check)
  idf   <- log10(n/sure)
  return(idf)
}


##
##
##  train document term matrix
##  Document-feature matrix of: 1,715,438 documents, 184,554 features (100% sparse).
TrainWcm
> head(TrainWcm[,1:4])
Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 4 features (70.8% sparse).
6 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    what changes will you
  text1    1       1    1   2
  text2    0       0    0   0
  text3    1       0    0   0
  text4    1       0    0   0
  text5    0       0    0   0
  text6    1       0    0   0

##
##
##  valid document term matrix
##  Document-feature matrix of: 391,836 documents, 184,554 features (100% sparse).
ValidWcm
> head(ValidWcm[,1:4])
Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 4 features (87.5% sparse).
6 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    what changes will you
  text1    1       0    0   0
  text2    0       0    0   0
  text3    1       0    0   1
  text4    0       0    0   0
  text5    0       0    0   0
  text6    0       0    0   0
##
##
##  Idf from train
WcmIdf <- Idf(TrainWcm)
##
##
##  First method
TrainTfdf <- TrainWcm
ValidTfdf <- ValidWcm
n <- seq(length(WcmIdf))
for( i in n ){
  TrainTfdf[,i] <- TrainWcm[,i]*WcmIdf[i]
  ValidTfdf[,i] <- ValidWcm[,i]*WcmIdf[i]
  cat("\r",i)
}
##
##
##  Second method
n <- seq(length(WcmIdf))
TrainTfidf <- pblapply(n, function(i) TrainWcm[,i] * WcmIdf[i]) %>% do.call("cbind", .)
ValidTfidf <- pblapply(n, function(i) ValidWcm[,i] * WcmIdf[i]) %>% do.call("cbind", .)
```

Comment: can you post some sample data for us to work with? Just paste the output of `head(df)` and format as code

Comment: Yes, I print head of dfm in the comment.

Comment: Fastest way to get document frequency is `docfreq()`. Supply an example and clearly explain your desired output and we can refine this further.

Answer (score 1):

As per Question, the **Valid** and **train** dfm need to have common ground, as far as I understood it, so one may try to combine those two document set or their respective corpus and then compute the mighty `TF-IDF` matrix.

And since both Valid and train have common columns so it will be easy to combine them or append one to other.

Later, after computing the `TF-IDF` matrix, you can partition them back to **train** and **Valid**.

Answer (score 0):

I use debug and modified dfm_tfidf, and get the solution.
parameter `idf` is output of `Idf` function above.

```
##
##
##  Tfidf
Tfidf <- function(dfm, idf = NULL){
  require(quanteda)
  if(is.null(idf)){
    output <- dfm_tfidf(dfm)
    return(output)
  }else{
    output <- dfm
    j      <- as(dfm, "dgTMatrix")@j + 1
    output@x <- dfm@x * idf[j]
    return(output)
  }
}
```